# Eclipse configure project as Maven problem

Tags: eclipse, maven, configure

I have created simple project with class Main and public static void main
and System.out.println("Hello world");
And after have configured as maven project.
After this main doesn't work:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: main/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: main.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

Why this happens? How to fix?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven clear project settings and also source folder.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try creating a simple project using an [archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html), and then compare the differences.
Suggest you choose the archetype maven-archetype-simple

`mvn archetype:generate -D archetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -D maven-archetype-simple -D groupId=com.mycompany.mygroup -D artifactId=myapp`

The import it to eclipse using prefererably the m2eclipse plugin or `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate the eclipse .project files etc.